# How to display values from database in a checkbox list?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to load the data from database to a checkbox list to display and select and here is my code. But it's not working so can anyone correct this code for me?

When i execute this i get the error message as "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\xampp\htdocs\test.php on line 70"

```
<?php   
    $section = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Section_Text FROM Section");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($section)){
   {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='Section' value ='Section_Text'";
    echo " />";
    echo $row['Section_Text'];

    echo "</td></tr><br/>";
   }

?>
```

Comment: ThiefMaster is right, in order to avoid such mistaked in the future , try using a better worksapce - such as eclipse PDT or zend.

Comment: Whats with the `<br/>` tag ? You echo rows for a table, dont use <br/> divider beetween table rows. And please paste the netire file. Also, use distinct(field)

Answer (score 1):

You have a `{` too much right after your while loop. Remove one of them and the code will work.

Besides that, you should really use PDO (or mysqli) instead of the deprecated `mysql` extension to access your database.

Comment: Which code line is 70 in your file ? put a note by this codeline , it will be helpful

Comment: I am not getting any error message now but the code is still not working. when i try to display numbers from an array in the checkbox list it works but when i try to display values from database it does not work.

Comment: try to run the query alone and see if there is a result

Comment: in this case, check your database table fields, thats where the error is

Comment: The query is working fine i tried the same by displaying in a dropdown box and its working.

Comment: try echo "<input type='checkbox' name='Section' value ='".($row['Section_Text'])."'";

Comment: I tried with "<input type='checkbox' name='Section' value ='".($row['Section_Text'])."'"; and its still not working.

Comment: Besides i am new to coding and Right now i am trying to build a simple web search to retrieve data from database for which i am using php and mysql so i just know things in bits and pieces, which is why i am not able to debug.

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop :

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($section)){
   {
```

Why are there two `{`? Delete one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the double `{` after the while declaration.

I suggest you to refactor your code a bit.

- Escape your output using `htmlentities($row['Section_Text'])`
- Don't repeat yourself using positional `$` printf notation
- Use `<label ... />` notation to keep your form accessible: [check this](http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/3b-ii-labels-checkboxes.html)

  ```
  <?php   
  $section = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Section_Text FROM Section");

  $n = 0;
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($section))
  {
      print "<tr><td>" . PHP_EOL;
      printf('<input type="checkbox" name="section_%2$d" id="section_%2$d" value="%1$s" />
           <label for="section_%2$d">%1$s</label>' . PHP_EOL,
            htmlentities($row['Section_Text'], ENT_QUOTES), $n++
      );
      print "</td></tr>" . PHP_EOL;
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 { in the while, remove one. and also get rid of the 
 tags, use css to get the desired padding